# How to check whether a non-assoc array is unique in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know whether the array `$arr` has duplicate elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`array_unique()` should work:

```
if (count(array_unique($arr)) == count($arr)) 
  echo "Array does not contain duplicate elements"; 
else
  echo "Array contains duplicate elements";
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a built in function for that. But you could do

```
if (count($arr) == count(array_unique($arr))
{
    //array has no unique elements
}
```

Comment: Arrays can't have duplicate keys. :)

Comment: re: deceze: which is also why `array_flip(array_flip($arr))` has the same result as `array_unique($arr)` (is quicker, too).

Comment: @pinkgothic Nice trick, but I'd still go with `array_unique` for readability. :)

Comment: **@deceze** : Agreed. And since array key types are restricted, the `array_flip()` version doesn't always work, either! But if you're just working with `int` and `string` values in your array, it's an option. Which is good, since if you have really large arrays (say, > 100 elements), `array_unique()` is cripplingly slow. :(